# Conversion to signed type behavior when out of range

Tags: c++, c++20, implicit-conversion, implementation-defined-behavior

Converting an integer to a signed type when the source value can't be represented in the destination type is according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#:%7E:text=If%20the%20destination%20type%20is%20signed,used%20to%20represent%20the%20destination%20type.)

> - implementation-defined (until C++20)
> - the unique value of the destination type equal to the **source value modulo 2^n**
>   where n is the number of bits used to represent the destination type (since C++20)

Also specified in [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#:%7E:text=The%20result%20of,signal%20is%20raised.) implementation-defined behavior, there is

> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is **reduced modulo 2^N** to be within range of the type; no signal is raised.

I guess there are saying the same thing. My question is isn't the reduced/moduloed result still maybe out of range of the destination signed type? Say `signed char c = 255`, 255 modulo 2^8 is still 255, unchanged. How does this moduloed result fit into the destination type?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60879095/11673310) shows a method to first invert the value and add 1, then prepend a signed bit. I'm not sure if that's what actually have been done.

What's the correct/standard way to interpret the emphasized part?

Comment: 255 is not "a unique value of the destination type".

Comment: The word "reduced" in "reduced modulo 2^N" has a specific mathematical meaning: "Find the unique allowable value which differs from the original value by an integer multiple of 2^N." The word "reduce" here does not mean "subtract". It instead refers to the fact that the set of possible answers is a reduced set from the set of all integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of these quotes are meant to say that the original value is taken, the modulo operation applied, and the result used as result of the conversion.

Instead they are meant to say that out of all values `v` representable in the destination type, the (unique) one for which the mathematical equality

```
s + m * 2^n = v
```

holds for some integer `m`, with `s` the source value, is chosen. It is said that `s` and `v` are *congruent modulo `2^n`* if they satisfy this condition or sometimes also that they are *equal modulo `2^n`*.

For `s = 255` with signed target of width `8`, `255` is not representable, but `-1` is and `v = -1` satisfies the equation with `m = -1`.

Answer (score 2):

> Say signed char = 255U, 255 modulo 2^8 is still 255

255 isn't **within range of the type** (of 8 bit signed integer).

One way to re-phrase the rule is that the converted result will be congruent with the unrepresentable result modulo 2^n.

-513, -257, -1, 255, 511 are all congruent modulo 256. Of the congruent numbers, only -1 is within the representable range of the signed type.

Comment: How is there another congruent operation? Is that indicated by the "equal" relation of the destination type?

Comment: @Masquue -1  modulo 256 is equal to 255 modulo 256. Hence, they are congruent modulo 256.

Comment: I realized my misunderstanding about the "modulo by 2^N" as being % operation. Thank you. Upvoted but another answer seems more rigorous, with a little math.

Comment: @eerorika: *"-1 modulo 256 is equal to 255 modulo 256"* From mathematical point of view, [not with C++ integers](https://godbolt.org/z/x8dEzcqYo) ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 It [can be](https://godbolt.org/z/Yz4Eh5vPn) ;) But yes, I'm talking about their residual classes, rather than the remainder operator of C++.

Comment: “added 127 characters in body”—I see what you did there.